# Capture git tag command with Jenkins sh() function

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm looking to use the `git tag --list '<pattern>'` command to fetch a list of git tags that match the pattern using the `sh()` function in Jenkins/Groovy.

I have been trying all kinds of things to get the whole output from the git command but nothing seems to do the trick.

If I use the `sh()` function with ls:

```
def ls = sh(
             script: "ls",
             returnStdout: true
             )
println(ls)
// or
println(ls.readLines())
```

I get the whole output, as expected.

But when using the `git tag` command, I always seem to only get the last "item".

```
sh(
   script: "git tag --list '${pattern}*'",
   returnStdout: true
   )
```

Whether I use `readLines()` or not, the output is always just the last item from the command

```
sh(
   // print all items on one row instead of columns
   script: "git tag --list '${pattern}*' --column=row",
   returnStdout: true
   )
```

Again with or without `readLines()` fetches only the last item

```
sh(
   // pipe output to remove spaces and add in comma
   script: "git tag --list '${pattern}*' | tr [:space:] ','",
   returnStdout: true
   )
```

And again, only the last item is fetched.

If I perform any of these git commands locally, I get the desired output and expected output from each one, but Jenkins seems to only capture the last item no matter what I do. I expect I am missing something obvious with the behavior of the git command. Anyone know why this is happening and how to get all the items?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
def tags = sh(script: """
                    git fetch --all --tags > /dev/null
                    git --no-pager tag --list '${pattern}*'
                """, returnStdout: true )
println(tags)
```

Comment: I gave this a go but for some reason the Jenkins pipeline hangs indefinitely on the first `git fetch --all --tags` command. I suspect its something strange with the way my company has the Jenkins client configured.